Buscar fecha en una lista de fechas en Python
Tengo una fecha que quiero identificar si está dentro de una listas de fechas. Mi código es este:
fecha=datetime.date(2024, 3, 29)
fechas_inhabiles = dias_inhabiles(fecha.year,  fecha.year)['ds']
bandera=0
if fecha in fechas_inhabiles:
  bandera=1
while bandera==1:
  fecha -= datetime.timedelta(days=1)
  bandera=0

Sin embargo, en la sentencia de if, no encuentra la fecha en la lista fechas_inhabiles, pero si se encuentra, adjunto una imagen que muestra los resultados que tengo.


Si fechas_inhabiles es una Serie de pandas, el operador in se aplica sobre los índices de la misma, no sobre los valores.
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> s = pd.Series(("Python", "Rust", "JS", "C++"), name="lenguajes")

>>> s
0    Python
1      Rust
2        JS
3       C++
Name: lenguajes, dtype: object

>>> "Rust" in s
False

>>> 2 in s
True

Para comprobar si existe entre los valores de la serie, tienes varias opciones, por ejemplo:
Convertir la Serie en un array de NumPy
fecha in fechas_inhabiles.to_numpy()

Este es quizás el método más simple y directo.
Convertirla en una lista
fecha in fechas_inhabiles.to_list()

Es otra posibilidad aunque no especialmente útil o eficiente, a no ser que queramos la lista para otras cosas.
Usar pandas.Series.isin()
fechas_inhabiles.isin([fecha]).any()

Este método es especialmente útil si quieres comprobar una lista de valores en vez de uno solo, es decir, comprobar si uno o varios valores de una lista están en la Serie (fechas_inhabiles.isin([fecha1, fecha2, ...]).any())
Usar pandas.Series.unique()
Si tuvieras valores repetidos y fueras a aplicar la comprobación repetidamente, se podría valora el uso de pandas.Series.unique():
fecha in fechas_inhabiles.unique()

pero en este caso sería ineficiente y no serviría de nada dado que tu serie ya es un conjunto de valores únicos.
También se podría valorar convertir la serie en conjunto (set), para aprovechar la eficiencia de las búsquedas en tablas hash, pero de nuevo, hay que valorar en cada caso concreto si merece la pena teniendo en cuenta las veces que vamos a realizar la comprobación y el sobrecoste de crear un nuevo contenedor.

Muchas gracias, justo se solucionó el problema al convertir la serie en un array de NumPy
